# Program not printing final outcome

Tags: java, image

My code is supposed to combine 2 objects from 2 images into one image then print it out. The first image has an object and white background. the second image is just a background. I need to replace the white background with the second image to create a new picture. My code doesn't print out the new picture. Any help?

```
import java.awt.*;

class Chroma
{
    public void newChroma (Picture noBGround, Picture newBGround)
    {
        int height = noBGround.getHeight();
        int width = noBGround.getWidth();

        Pixel[] pixels = noBGround.getPixels();
        Pixel[] pixels2 = newBGround.getPixels();

        Pixel p = null;
        Pixel p2 = null;
        for(int y=0; y<height; y++){
            for(int x=0; x<width; x++){


                p = pixels[x]; 
                int red = p.getRed();
                int green = p.getGreen();
                int blue = p.getBlue();

                p2 = pixels2[x];
                int red2 = p2.getRed();
                int green2 = p2.getGreen();
                int blue2 = p2.getBlue();

                if (red == 255 || green == 255 || blue == 255) {
                    p.setRed(red2);
                    p.setGreen(green2);
                    p.setBlue(blue2);
                }
                else {
                    p.setRed(red);
                    p.setGreen(green);
                    p.setBlue(blue);
                }     
            }
        }

        noBGround.write("ChromaKey.jpg");
        noBGround.explore();
    }
}
public class ChromaKey
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Picture noBGround = new Picture("img1.jpg");
        Picture newBGround = new Picture("img2.jpg");

        Chroma obj = new Chroma();
    }
}
```

Comment: You create the `Chroma` class , but you do not appear to be calling the `newChroma(Picture, Picture)` method

Comment: I made the change except now the image being shown an printed has no changes to it. I'm only getting the picture with  white background as my result.

Answer (score 0):

One quick issue I see is that you don't actually call the newChroma method in your Chroma class.  After you say `Chroma obj = new Chroma();` you should follow up with `obj.newChroma();`.

Also in your `newChroma()` method you don't actually do anything with the pixel p that you create.  And you probably mean to say `red == 255 && blue == 255 && green == 255`, using and instead of or.

Comment: Now it's only printing the one with a white background. No changes are being made to incorporate the new background.

Comment: Where are you getting your `Picture` and `Pixel` classes from. I think maybe these are not getting put into the image after you change them. Therefore, the image that get written hasn't been changed.